# How can I link Nginx frontend to tomcat backend without using GatewayAPI?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, tomcat, devops

I have Angular frontend hosted under nginx server and spring boot backend hosted under tomcat server. I want to link between backend and frontend without gatewayAPI.

which config file do I configure ?

Nginx.conf :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  localhost;

root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

gzip on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        client_max_body_size 300M;

location / {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    expires off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
 location /api/APP/ {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    expires off;
    proxy_pass http://@ip:8080/backend-1.0/api/APP/;
}
 location /api/APP/login {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    expires off;
    proxy_pass http://@ip:8080/backend-1.0/api/APP/login;
}
 location /api/APP/find/user/by/login {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    expires off;
    proxy_pass http://@ip:8080/backend-1.0/api/APP/find/user/by/login;
}
```

}